# Run Eclipse save actions on every file in a project

Tags: eclipse

We are using Eclipse save actions to strip trailing white-space, organize imports and some rudimentary code formatting. This was not always so, and the project is quite big and old so many times when we edit a file we get a lot of source control changes that are not immediately relevant to the commit. What we often do then is that we commit the formatting without the code change separately and then the code change on top of that.

It would be very convenient to be able to just run the save actions on every Java file in our project and then commit that once and for all, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do that. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right click on the project, choose `Source` -> `Clean up...` to run the save actions, and under `Source` you will also have `Organize imports` and `Format`.

Comment: If "Source" is not available on the Project, try right clicking on the source folder.

Comment: Answered own question in the same minute... o.O But thanks anyway - answer was helpful for me.

Comment: This solution makes the same sort of actions available, but will not automatically run the same actions that were configured in `Project properties` -> `Java Editor` -> `Save Actions`. This runs the actions that are configured in `Project properties` -> `Java Code Style` -> `Clean Up`. For my projects these are not the same (although not intentionally).